# Vuejs Laravel Axios create request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a vuejs method which implements axios to send a put/create request over to my laravel api create method passing over some data.

```
create(data) {
    this.mute = true;
    window.axios.put('/api/showreels/create', {data}).then(({ data }) => {
        this.showreels.push(new Showreel(data));
        this.mute = false;
    }).catch(error => {
            document.write(error.response.data);
    });
},
```

My api.php is setup with the following resource

```
//Showreel
Route::resource('/showreels' , 'ShowreelController' , [
 'except' => ['edit', 'show', 'store']
]);
```

And I have a create method to handle the request and update persist the data. (Which I have added a load of debugging in)

```
    /**
 * Create a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create(Request $request)
{

    $message = 'sdfsdfsdf';
    $message =  $message . $request->heading . 'BALLS';

    \App::abort(500, $message);

    $showreel = new Showreel();
    $showreel->heading = $request->heading;
    $showreel->subheading = $request->subheading;
    $showreel->detail =  $request->heading;
    $showreel->youtubeid =  $request->youtubeid;


    $showreel->heading = "test";
    $showreel->subheading = "test";
    $showreel->detail = "test";
    $showreel->youtubeid = "test";



    $showreel->save();

    return response($showreel->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

However laravel is giving me this error.

[image]

Not sure why I am getting this error?

Comment: I have figured out that the put request was calling my update method and not the create method. Now I just need to figure out how to create since my api is not allowing a post request.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I had the STORE option disabled in my api.php which was closing down the post request option. The post request now takes me through to my store method in laravel.